# Create dynamic Flask-SocketIO pages based on n json files

Tags: python, json, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

i wondering is it possible to create Flask-SocketIO pages, without writing routes and functions in advance? I have a folder there n .json files, quantity and names of those files will constantly change, based on each file i need to create a page with a js table that will constantly updating, as long as .json file in the folder. It will look like this:
Static Apples.html: (page with list of links that will lead to each apple type page with js table on it)
-Gala (link to Gala.html that will expand on Apples.html and its content will be based Gala.json that in the folder, and should be dynamically updated with socket-io )
-Fuji (link to Fuji.html that will expand on Apples.html and its content will be based Fuji.json that in the folder, and should be dynamically updated with socket-io)
-etc (as many links as many json files in the folder)
How do i create something like this? Is it even possible? Maybe i need to use some other techology?

Comment: Basically you are asking for an entire application built from scratch. My recommendation is that you try to build this application yourself and only ask about the parts that you don't know, because as it stands this is a wide open question that covers HTTP, Socket.IO, file system watches, HTML, JavaScript and so on.

Comment: Well, i'm not asking for whole aplication, its more how do you guys creating dynamic routes, and sending data to that dynamic routes, maybe other examples will help to write the code.